# convert an List<Keyvaluepair> to a specific ICollection type C#

Tags: c#

`Please am new-bee to programming and also have searched for the last few hours on a solution but cant find one; So here is my problem:

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` I want to convert the value pair at run-time to a `ICollection<T>`

Where T is the Type of object (The Value pair).

The purpose of the conversion is to pass the values into the PropertyInfo.SetValue(obj, val) method. Where val is the ICollection

```
public object TheMEthod( object objreactor, List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> objactor) {

  Type tyr2 = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(objactor.First().Value.GetType());

  ICollection list = (ICollection) Activator.CreateInstance(tyr2);
  list = (ICollection) objactor.Select(l => l.Value).Distinct().ToList();

                objreactor.GetType().GetProperty(objactor.First().Key)?.SetValue(objreactor, Convert.ChangeType( list, objactor.First().Value.GetType()), null);

            //else return exception

            return objreactor;


        }
```

This returns the error object must implement iconvertible c#"

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? The List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> is already an ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> (the List<T> supports that interface) or did you need it converted to something else?

Comment: When I pass the Value pair of the code (don't need key )

Comment: public object JoinEntitytoEntity_Activity( object objreactor, List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> objactor)
        {        
                Type tyr2 = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(objactor.First().Value.GetType());

                ICollection list = (ICollection) Activator.CreateInstance(tyr2);
                list = (ICollection) objactor.Select(l => l.Value).Distinct().ToList();              objreactor.GetType().GetProperty(objactor.First().Key)?.SetValue(objreactor, Convert.ChangeType( list, objactor.First().Value.GetType()), 
 return objreactor;
 }

Comment: Sorry the above does not make much sense

Comment: @ufo add it in the question (edit link) not in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the keyvalue pair has an `object` as the value, but you need it to be a specific object `T` you'll need to cast it. This will only work if the `Value` *really is* the right type.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = ....

ICollection<TheRealObject> coll = list.Select(x => x.Value)  // Select the Values
                                      .Cast<TheRealObject>() //Cast them to your type
                                      .ToList(); // turn it to a list
```

Note that `List<T>` *is a* `ICollection<T>` so you can almost certainly pass this list to a `SetProperty` expecting an `ICollection<T>`

Comment: The issue with the above code is that I want to be able to set dynamically the 'TheRealObject" Type at realtime for different object types